# Ошибка при запуске Kafka (kafka_2.11-2.0.0) на этапе запуска zookeper

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

Хочу запустить apache kafka на Win7. (На компе с Win10 все прошло гладко).
Использую инструкцию QuickStart с сайта Apach kafka.
Распаковал папку c файлам kaffka на диск C:\

Первым шагом пытаюсь запустить zookeper

```
C:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.propertie
```

и сразу же ошибка (Inavlid config, exiting abnormally)

[image: ОШИБКА]

что установлено по JAVA:

[image: JAVA KIT]

Ругается на файл конфигурации для zookeeper, но он с дефолтными настройками.
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Путь к файлам с конфигурацией
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `config\zookeeper.properties file is missing` в эксепшне говорит само за себя. проверяйте пути и имена файлов

Comment: файл на месте (см. скриншот выше), если копирую папку на систему с Win10 и делаю все тоже самое то все работает

Comment: А в Win10 запускаетесь из папки с кафкой видимо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с путями.
Вы запускаетесь из папки профиля - `c:\Users\Admin`. Путь к бинарнику указываете абсолютный - `C:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\` А путь к конфигу указываете относительный - `config\zookeeper.properties`. Само собой, в `c:\Users\Admin` даже если и есть папка `config`, то файла `zookeeper.properties` в ней вряд ли найдётся.

Решение:
1. Используйте абсолютные пути и там, и там:
`C:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties`
2. Перейдите в папку `C:\kafka_2.11-2.0.0\` и выполните эту команду там.

Comment: Точно, спасибо большое, маленький опыт работы с CMD)